# Cypher syntax error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am getting the following error while trying to execute Cypher from the Java API:

> org.neo4j.cypher.SyntaxException: Invalid input ')': expected whitespace, comment, '.',     node labels, '[', "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or '}' (line 1, column 46)
>
> "MERGE (n:C3CASEID {id: {id} , title: {title} ) RETURN n"

Unable to locate the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it: missed the `}` bracket.so it should be

```
MERGE (n:C3CASEID {id: {id} , title: {title}} )
RETURN n;
```

Comment: Good catch - now just mark this as an answer and you'll be all set.